# Finding the string in range of numbers

Tags: javascript, excel, math, excel-formula

Let's say, in the string *"91910500"*, there are numbers (00, 10, 19, 50, 91, 105, 500, 919, 9191, 1910, 1050, 10500, etc...).

You have a range number from 0000000001 to 99999999999. And you have to find a string which contains all the numbers from that range. whatever you guess a number from that range, you will find that number in the main string.

What will be the main string for that range? With the following the code, I still see duplicate in main key.

```
var s = "";

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log('Searching the number ' + i);
  d = i.toString;

  if (s.indexOf(d) >= 0) {} else {
    s = s.concat(i);
  }

  console.log('Key is \n' + s);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: @n4m31ess_c0d3r yes, I add the code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you just need to update 2 lines:

> for (i = 0;  i < 100; i++) {

to:

```
for (i = 100 - 1; i >= 0; i--){
```

And:

> d = i.toString;

to:

```
d = i.toString();
```